# Bold text in result set from the text

Tags: flutter

I am trying to find a solution to this problem.

I have a text input, and when the user types in the text input "trending". I return a result set of text containing the word trending. What I want to do is display the text that was entered bold (example: **trending**items).

The solution I have currently works, sort of.

```
    String resultText = "trending items";
    int x = resultText.toLowerCase().indexOf(queriedText.toLowerCase()); // Problem happens here, I get -1 as a result
    List parts = [ // I use this list to display in a Rich Text to adjust the style of the text the user input
      if (resultText.substring(0, x).isNotEmpty) resultText.substring(0, x).trim(),
      queriedText,
      if (resultText.substring(x + queriedText.length).isNotEmpty)
        resultText.substring(x + queriedText.length).trim()
    ];

    int idx = resultText.toLowerCase().indexOf(queriedText.toLowerCase());
    while (idx > 0 && idx < resultText.length) {
      String _subT = resultText.substring(idx + queriedText.length);
      idx = _subT.toLowerCase().indexOf(queriedText.toLowerCase());
    }
```

If the user enters `trending items` but the result set has `trendingitems`, `int x` is returned a value of -1 which is where the widget crashes (understandably).

What I would like to get is the following:

This scenario works:

- User types: trending
- Display: **trending** items in the list

This scenario crashes:

- User types: trending items
- Display: **trending items** in the list

TIA

Comment: in display text you can try with the `richtext` i hope it will work for you

Comment: instead of using substring, go one by one until you reach g, if (T), if (R), ....

Comment: @JahidulIslam I am using richtext, this is just a portion of the code before I use the `parts` in the rich text

Answer (score 0):

I've made a package for this: [text_chunk_styling](https://pub.dev/packages/text_chunk_styling)

```yaml
dependencies:
  text_chunk_styling: ^2.0.1
```

Basically it will apply a custom `TextStyle` to some part of your text in your case the code would be something like this:

### Sample 1

```dart
TextChunkStyling(
  text: 'trending items',
  highlightText: const ['trending'],
  highlightTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
)
```

[image]

### Sample 2

```dart
TextChunkStyling(
  text: 'trending items',
  highlightText: const ['trending items'],
  highlightTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
)
```

[image]